# I need to speed up a nested loop in python that makes trillions of loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, nested-loops

`filtradas` is around 500000 elements and `_13` around 2000000 the minimum time i have achieved is like 4 hours using cython, but I need to do it in less than an hour, how can i do it?

Both lists have string elements with 1, 2 or X the X can be changed for a 3

```
for i in filtradas:
        for x in _13:
            aciertos=0
            if i[0]==x[0]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[1]==x[1]:
                aciertos+=1         
            if i[2]==x[2]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[3]==x[3]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[4]==x[4]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[5]==x[5]:
                aciertos+=1         
            if i[6]==x[6]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[7]==x[7]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[8]==x[8]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[9]==x[9]:
                aciertos+=1         
            if i[10]==x[10]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[11]==x[11]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[12]==x[12]:
                aciertos+=1
            if i[13]==x[13]:
                aciertos+=1
            if aciertos>=nroaciertos:
                filtradas13.append(i)
                break
    return filtradas13
```

Comment: Can there be duplicates? if not, you can use the set object. If there are duplicates, it's probably going to be much faster to sort the two arrays first, and then walk both lists.

Comment: Are you on linux? Multiprocessing may help on a forking system.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for commenting. I am on windows with an fx 8350

Comment: @BillLynch Thanks for commenting. i have eliminated the duplicates on both lists with set

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean that the X __can be__ replaced with a 3? Does that mean that the X can either be replaced with the empty string or the string `'3'`?

Comment: It can be replaced with string 3, because if its better to split the string into integers, but really i dont know if its faster or not to split it into integers

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` is worth a try. In this example I suspect that the time to convert to a numpy array isn't worth the compare but if your data was imported into numpy in the first place, it may go faster.

```
import numpy as np

_13_array = [np.array(list(x))for x in _13]
for i in filtradas:
    filtradas_array = np.array(list(i))
    for x in _13_array:
        aciertos = (x==filtradas_array).sum()
        if aciertos>=nroaciertos:
            filtradas13.append(i)
            break
```

Comment: with that aciertos is always 0, i am not an expert in numpy but i think that it doesnt works fine with strings, the lists have elements similar to "11211X12111X1211"

Comment: Right, it would have to be something like `np.array(tuple(x))` and `np.array(tuple(i))` to convert the strings to columns.

Comment: @diegow98 - i wasn't sure of the format. I've updated.

Comment: Its as fast as the other code using cython, i will compile it with cython tomorrow and check the speed, thank you. But i still need to check if it works fine, because i dont understand the part aciertos=(x==filtradas_array).sum() hahaha

Comment: `numpy` represents data as low level C or Fortran arrays and then applies python operations to the entire array, usually releasing the python GIL. So, `(x==filtradas_array)` becomes a low level boolean array of the comparison of the elements of the two arrays, which is really 1's and 0's. `.sum()` then sums the values in that array. So its the same as the `+=` you do when items match.

Comment: I tried and the minimum time was 2h i need it to work in less than 1 hour, i tried with vectorize the function and it didnt worked, with cython the time is a little bit less than python with numpy

Comment: @tdelaney I think that the solution would be find a numpy function to substitue the for loop, but i cant find it

Comment: @tdelaney i finded a way with numba to speed the loops, but the aciertos = (x==filtradas_array).sum() i think its not working